# How do I open a console app and run a command in VB?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying open a console application with `VB`. You've probably heard of `Grand Theft Auto` Series and I'm a *Modder*. So I'm developing a application that can execute commands of a console application (to replace and add files to a archive).

I'm using the following code to execute and run a command:

```
Shell ("("my application.exe")
sendkeys.send = ("o")
sendkeys.send = ("p")
sendkeys.send = ("e")
sendkeys.send = ("n")
sendkeys.send = ("{ENTER}")
```

When I run this script, I get a lot of application windows pop-ups, hundreds of them. What should I do?

Comment: (1) The shell command doesn't look correct. For example, the parens don't match. Normally "open" can be sent as one send command. (2) Add a delay (sleep) between the shell and when you start sending commands in order to give the app time to open and to get ready to receive commands. (3) Look into *AutoIt*, and *System.Windows.Automation*.

Comment: Use the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class to start an application programatically. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is this really VB.NET? It seems more like VBScript or something.